# Calculating differences of subsequent elements of a sequence in F#

Tags: f#

I have a sequence of floats in F#, and I need to get a sequence defined of `(Math.Log currentElement)/(Math.Log previousElement)`. Obviously it will be shorter than the original sequence by one element.

What is the most elegant way to achieve this in F#? I was thinking to use a seq{} expression with a for loop inside, but even then handling the first element in a reasonably nice way seems difficult...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
items |> Seq.pairwise |> Seq.map (fun (x, y) -> log y / log x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer:

```
let f (x, y) = (log y) / (log x)

let ans = s |> Seq.pairwise |> Seq.map f
```