# Calculating differences of subsequent elements of a sequence in scala

Tags: scala

I would like to do [almost exactly this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12161015/644812) in scala. Is there an elegant way?

Specifically, I just want the difference of adjacent elements in a sequence. For example

```
input = 1,2,6,9
output = 1,4,3
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this?

```
scala> List(1, 2, 6, 9).sliding(2).map { case Seq(x, y, _*) => y - x }.toList
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 3)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is one that uses recursion and works best on Lists

```
def differences(l:List[Int]) : List[Int] = l match {
  case a :: (rest @ b :: _) => (b - a) :: differences(rest)
  case _ => Nil
}
```

And here is one that should be pretty fast on Vector or Array:

```
def differences(a:IndexedSeq[Int]) : IndexedSeq[Int] = 
  a.indices.tail.map(i => a(i) - a(i-1))
```

Of course there is always this:

```
def differences(a:Seq[Int]) : Seq[Int] = 
  a.tail.zip(a).map { case (x,y) => x - y }
```

Note that only the recursive version handles empty lists without an exception.